# Python SQL Data to Array (like csv)

Tags: python, sql, arrays, plsql

currently I am trying to read my SQL-Data to an array in python.
I am new to python so please be kind ;)

My csv-export can be read easily:

`data = pd.read_csv('esoc_data.csv', header = None)
 x = data[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]`

This one picks the second column (starting from 1, not 0) till 12th column of my dataset. I need this data in this exact format!

Now I want to do the same with the data I get from my SQL-fetch.

```
names = [i for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

This one gives me my data with all (0-12) columns and separated by ","
Result:

> [(name@mail.com', 13, 13, 0, 24, 2, 0, 20, 3, 0, 31, 12, 2), (...)]

Now .. how do I get this into my "specific" format I mentioned before?
I just need the numbers like this:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7    8    9  10  11  12
0    13  13   0  24   2   0  20    3    0  31  12   2
1    21   0   0  24   0   0  32    0    0  30   0   0
2     9   7   0  26  31   0  19   27    0  30  32   2
```

I'm sorry if this is peanuts for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a multi-loop for this, something like

```
def our_method():
    parent_list = list()
    for name in names:
        child_list = list()
        for index, item in enumerate(name):
            if index != 0:
                child_list.append(item)
        parent_list.append(child_list)
    return parent_list
```